# How can i protect a directory (and its files) using sessions

Tags: javascript, php, security, session

I'm working on a project, where each user has a folder where he uploads his files.
The problem: Any user can simply type the path and filename to download.
Is there any way to protect this using sessions, which is how the system has the code of who is logged in?

(remembering that each folder has the code of its user, example: user_1, user_2 etc).

It may be useful to protect the file itself.

Comment: This may help you https://www.eriksmistad.no/how-to-restrict-user-access-to-content-in-folders-using-php-and-apache-htaccess-files/

Comment: either move the folder outside web root (prefered) or apply access rules per-directory, then you have to serve the files in the directory via a script that can determine authorisation

Answer (score 0):

### $_SESSION

A solution would be the php global variable [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) :

Example:

```php
<?php
session_start(); // This function has to be called every time, you work with $_SESSION

if ($_SESSION["password"] === $userpw) {

    // data can be accessed

} else {

    // access denied, redirect to example.php
    header("Location: ../example.php");

}
```

[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

I hope, it helps...